# What Exactly are Digital and Analog Signals?

Tags: networking

While researching networking, i came across the term "Digital Signals" and "Analog Signals". According to the majority of sources ive viewed online, people are saying that an analog signal is a continuous flow of data, and that a digital signal is segments of data, or somthing of the like, but thats pretty dificult to visualize or put into perspective. Can anyone help me to understand what exactly a digital and analog signal is concretely?

Comment: A digital signal could be something as simple as looking at the voltage, and if it is `0` the value is `0`, but if it is `+5` the value is `1`. You then have discreet binary values. An analog signal value could be any value of the voltage, so you could have a value of `2.5` or `10.33` or any other value.

Comment: Thanks, that puts it into perspective pretty well! Some people say that every signal is technically an analog signal (like voltage, in your example), but its how we interpret it that determines weather its a digital signal. Would you say thats somewhat true? @RonMaupin

Comment: Well, they say that because the voltage takes time to ramp up from `0` to `+5`, but it is meaningless except what the voltage is at a particular time. The voltage is analog at any given time period, but it is either above or below the threshold at a meaningful time. For example a 1 Mbps signal is only meaningful every one millionth of a second, but meaningless between those periods as it is changing.

Comment: An analog signal is continuous, but digital is measured at specific times.

Comment: Ohhhhh ok i get it, that makes perfect sense. Thanks a ton! @RonMaupin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly,

An analog signal uses a continuous range of values to represent information.

A digital signal uses discrete values (0 and 1) to represent information.

You can read more at https://www.guru99.com/analog-vs-digital.html

Comment: Alright, I can settle with that. One last thing, do you have any comment on why data on the internet is transported in analog signals, and computers use digital signals?

Comment: "_data on the internet is transported in analog signals_ No, it is not.

Comment: That's not exactly true.  The "data" on the Internet, being a product of digital computers, is digital.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by that exactly? Its a tad confusing.

Comment: @KeylimePi You could argue that if you look *very* closely, everything's analog. But it really depends on how you interpret signals, and in today's technology there's very little analog left.

Comment: @KeylimePi The signals on the Internet are ones and zeros— digital

Comment: everything above physical layer is zeros and ones. Physical layer's job is to map zeroes and ones to signals and then map the signal back to zeros and ones. And physical layer would probably do a lot of optimizations, knowing that the values trasmitted are only zeroes and ones.